# Java ClassNotFoundException for scala import in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, maven, classnotfoundexception

I have a project with mixed scala and java code. But I am unable to use scala objects inside java class. No matter what I do, it's throwing me `ClassNotFoundException` for the scala imports.

Example :

```
import scala.collection.Seq;

public class TestScalaImport {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException{
    try {
        Class.forName("scala.collection.Seq");
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
       throw e;
    }
 }
}
```

I have my scala library in the classpath, in run configurations and I am using Eclipse.
How do I resolve this ?

**EDIT**

Relevant pom snippet :

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
    <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>compile</id>
            <goals>
            <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>compile</phase>
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <id>test-compile</id>
            <goals>
            <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
            <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I am using Scala library version 2.10

Comment: Name of the jar you use for scala? (or better relevant part of your pom.xml)

Comment: Also does it work from command-line (is the issue specific to eclipse)

Comment: the pom.xml shown declares a scala plugin, not a scala dependency!

Comment: Thats the only scala relevant part in pom. The scala library is added separately through build path in eclipse.

Comment: Just use maven dependencies if you use a maven project

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem though. The scala library is added separately because the scala-ide plugin in eclipse gets it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the jar in the library of java build path of project in eclipse as below:

```
Project->properties->Java Build Path->Libraries->Add External Jars
```

Comment: Just extract the jar and look weather your desired class is inside the jar or is it inside the jar again.

Comment: It's a part of the Scala library, and it is there in the jar.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off creating a simple [SBT](http://www.scala-sbt.org/) project and letting the [sbteclipse](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse) plugin generate the Eclipse project files for you.